# Configuration differential amplifier in different power condition

Tags: differential-amplifier

[image]

On the left-hand side is a typical differential amplifier with Vcc and -Vcc.

On the right-hand side I kept Vcc but changed -Vcc to GND. Hence there are many things wrong with that configuration if I keep the other components unchanged.

What should I do to configure the differential amplifier on the right with Vcc and GND?

Comment: I try to find another configuration in Sedra Smith book's but seem like they tend to use Vcc and -Vcc instead of Vcc and GND, so I cant find a differential amplifier with Vcc and GND.

Comment: Start [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0agg.png)...

Comment: Do you *understand* why the right can't work?

Comment: I ask because you asked 4 questions in 5 hours, without even waiting for an answer to the first one. That is typical behaviour of someone who's "in over their head", and needs to work from basics instead of trying to understand basics (like this!) and very complex circuits (like your [complete audio amplifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/665784/how-to-choose-suitable-value-for-all-resistor-capacitor-diode-in-audio-amplier) parametrization question). Slow down! You're going to get burnout at this rate. Learning electronics is sequential. You need to understand the transistor

Comment: (and why it needs a Collector-Emitter Voltage \$\ne0\$ to function) before you can understand a current mirror, and you need to understand a current mirror before you can understand a current amplifier… You're trying to get an answer to 4 questions that would require you to learn the same basics, and then might answer themselves. So, get these basics.  No use giving you 4 answers you don't understand, just to get the 5. question that you could again answer yourself had you taken the time to learn the basics instead of asking the previous questions.

Comment: I'm sorry Muller, Now I know the right cant work. That is why I try to find a sample for Vcc GND. One way to find is to ask on the stack. I'm sorry if it offends you because my knowledge is narrow.

Comment: @periblepsis Yes I will try, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I'll write a short note about the first area of study: *the differential amplifier* used as the input stage for an audio amplifier.

(This is ***not*** a pre-amplifier stage. Those are for specialized input devices, such as the electret microphone. Pre-amplifier design is all about the input transducer and it's various requirements for conditioning the signal before it is passed on to the following input stage. Another topic for another day.)

Below, reading from upper left, then to upper right, then to lower left, then to lower right, are the various topologies that you need to apprehend reasonably well:

[image]

The first starts out just converting the diverted current into a voltage signal by inserting a resistor into the collector leg. (The other collector could also have a resistor in its collector leg, as I know you are already aware. But then you'd have to deal with a differential signal output, which you already are having trouble with, and I think it is more important that you avoid that 'difficulty' and instead just figure out and understand how to use a half of it as a single-ended output.) Most of the time, this upper left topology isn't used. But don't move away from studying this one until you are confident calculating its voltage gain given a current source value and a resistor value.

The second uses a current mirror as a load and vastly improves the resulting gain. Here, the resulting gain will require that you understand the idea of \$r_o\$ and the Early Effect. Again, don't move away from this until you can confidently gather up the voltage gain given the Early Effect present. (In the idealized case of no Early Effect it can be seen as transconductance.)

The third case uses a cascode stage. You ***will*** find this topology (or a closely related one) used in BJT opamps. This improves the gain of the input stage enough to sometimes be worth the extra trouble.

The fourth case converts the current mirror to a Wilson mirror, for a relatively large improvement in gain.

This is just the first stage.

I'd recommend then spending time studying various incarnations of the output stage. Not just class-AB but also class-A. And at some point get a clue about the value of a Zobel for the output (oscillation due to various forms of speaker loads and cabling.)

Once you've settled on the type of output stage (and feel confident about them) and the input stage, all you have left to worry about is the intermediate stage (often just called the VAS) that mediates between your chosen input and output stages. There's more to study there, of course. But with the input and output stages in hand, there's fewer forms to worry about for the middle and you can narrow your scope of ideas. And of course, you do need to understand NFB and hooking that up, properly, too.

It would also help a lot if you focus on a headphone amplifier, first. These require only milliwatt outputs and this means far less complexity. You don't have to worry much about the power supply itself (it's easy for low power like this) and you don't need to worry about thermal tracking or dissipation issues, though you still need to worry about ambient operating temperature variations. (Emitter degeneration helps with discrete parts, with a voltage gain cost, and/or you can buy matched BJT pairs.)

(Of course, designing current sources and vbe-multipliers are yet still other specialized areas to gather up. The learning doesn't ever really stop.)

Comment: Thank you for that note.

Answer (score 3):

> *My question is. What should I do to config right differential
> amplifier with Vcc and GND.*

Generate \$\frac{V_{CC}}{2}\$ and feed that to the nodes that were previously grounded on the left hand diagram. Try this: -

[image]

Comment: Yes I will try.

Comment: Can I have a question. First, I feed Vcc/2 to two Base of BJT, then how can I merge Vcc/2 of two node with the small signal from Vsine (50...100mV, 20 - 20.000KHz).

Comment: You feed Vcc/2 to one base and the signal to the other but, you reference the signal to Vcc/2 as you would have done on your left diagram @Southgoodman

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/VrIHCHT

Comment: Did you mean that I should set DC offset for Vsine is Vcc? However, I cant set it like that.

Comment: I've added a picture. If you must, you can connect the sinewave input via a series capacitor and, put a 10k resistor from the base to Vcc/2.